# Handlebars & Webpack: Including a template from a variable

Tags: javascript, webpack, handlebars.js

I am passing the name of the template to templateParametrs, how do I output this template?

webpack.config.js

```
function generateHtmlPlugins() {
  const viewList = fs.readdirSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './src/view'));
  viewList.splice(-1);
  return viewList.map(view => {
    const [ name ] = view.split('.');
    return new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: `${ name }.html`,
      //inject: false,
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/layout/index.handlebars'),
      templateParameters: {
        'view': name
      },
    })
  })
}
```

rules for handlebars:

```
{
        test: /\.handlebars$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'handlebars-loader',
            options: {
              debug: true,
              partialDirs: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/view'),
                path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/component')
              ],
            }
          }
        ]
}
```

layout/index.handlebars

```
  {{> header}}
  <section class="content">
    {{> (lookup . 'view') }}
  </section>
  {{> footer }}
```

[browser error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRdSH.png)
[view folder contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruQMh.png)